# How to use SSL Certificate with ActiveMQ without self signed certificate

Tags: java, ssl, https, activemq-classic

The [ActiveMQ SSL documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl) states:

> ActiveMQ includes key and trust stores that reference a dummy self signed cert

As per configuring SSL on ActiveMQ it is mentioned to provide the file url of broker keystore file.

```xml
    <bean id="SecureConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector">
        <property name="port" value="8162" />
        <property name="keystore" value="file:${activemq.conf}/broker.ks" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>
```

I have purchased an SSL certificate. How can i use that with ActiveMQ? The files I have are a `.cer` file and a `.key` file.

Should I first [convert](https://www.thesslstore.com/resources/tomcat-ssl-installation/) the `.cer` files to `.jks` file format and then configure it in ActiveMQ Jetty?

Is that how it is supposed to be done? Maybe I am missing something completely due to lack of knowledge in this area.

I cannot use the method explained by ActiveMQ because it requires both client and broker handshake and in this case the client is the 3rd party app and we have no control there.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate definitely must be in JKS format as that is the format which Java uses (and ActiveMQ is written in Java). Once the certificate is converted just reference it in the ActiveMQ configuration as described in the documentation. It should be really straight-forward.

If your certificate is signed by a trusted authority then the client will trust it implicitly and won't need to import it into a truststore of some kind. Using a truststore is necessary for "self-signed" certificates (which are used in the ActiveMQ documentation) since they are *not* signed by a trusted authority.

Comment: Okay. But i am having issues while converting the .cer file to .jks format. The error i got is Input not an X.509 certificate.

Can you please tell me the exact way to convert the .cer file to .jks format. I am following the link mentioned in the question.

Comment: I think you should create a new question about the actual certificate conversion. Please include the commands you're using as well as the output from those commands. Thanks!